# How can I get user's location when app is in background or killed in android and ios both platforms using react native?

Tags: react-native, background, location

I am working on an app that tracks driver's location to show on user's map but I am having some difficulties in tracking driver's location when app is in background or killed.

I have tried:
https://github.com/darron1217/react-native-background-geolocation

```
      const Token = useSelector(state => state.Auth.AccessToken);

      BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
      desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
      stationaryRadius: 50,
      distanceFilter: 50,
      notificationTitle: 'Demo App recording your location',
      notificationText: 'enabled',
      debug: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      locationProvider:  Platform.OS === 'android'
         ? BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER
         : BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
      interval: 10000,
      fastestInterval: 10000,
      activitiesInterval: 2000,
      stopOnStillActivity: false,
      url: CONSTANTS.BaseUrl + 'driver/updateCoordinate',
      syncUrl: CONSTANTS.BaseUrl + 'driver/updateCoordinate',
      httpHeaders: {
        Authorization: Token,
      },
      postTemplate: {
        latitude: '@latitude',
        longitude: '@longitude',
      },
    });
```

this gives me location while app is in background(not killed).
This package takes some props of url and params, I tried that but still not updating location when app is in background or killed.

I want to get the driver's location when the app is in background or killed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using a sticky service, look at this for android :
[article](https://medium.com/@ross_12208/android-location-tracking-foreground-background-force-killed-app-accuracy-aspects-24a151629f22)

Be carefull about android policy on background location : [limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

In my company we have develloped a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mobeye/react-native-geolocation) for geolocation, it's able to catch background when app is in background but not when app is killed.